# How can I concatenate multiple ArrayLists into one?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have to write a code that rolls 10 dice "N" number of times. I have to make a histogram of the results (10 through 60) using "*" to show the bell curve that *should* appear. How can I combine all the different ArrayLists i have to make my code look much cleaner? Is there a simpler way to do this all together?

I am getting the correct results; I just need a cleaner or more efficient way to show my code.

```
public class TenDice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of trials: ");
        int roll = scan.nextInt();


        ArrayList<String> results10 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results11 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results12 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results13 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results14 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results15 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results16 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results17 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results18 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results19 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results20 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results21 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results22 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results23 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results24 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results25 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results26 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results27 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results28 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results29 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results30 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results31 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results32 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results33 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results34 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results35 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results36 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results37 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results38 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results39 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results40 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results41 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results42 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results43 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results44 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results45 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results46 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results47 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results48 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results49 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results50 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results51 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results52 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results53 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results54 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results55 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results56 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results57 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results58 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results59 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> results60 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < roll; i++) {

            double dice1 = Math.random();
            dice1 = (int) (dice1 * 6);

            double dice2 = Math.random();
            dice2 = (int) (dice2 * 6);

            double dice3 = Math.random();
            dice3 = (int) (dice3 * 6);

            double dice4 = Math.random();
            dice4 = (int) (dice4 * 6);

            double dice5 = Math.random();
            dice5 = (int) (dice5 * 6);

            double dice6 = Math.random();
            dice6 = (int) (dice6 * 6);

            double dice7 = Math.random();
            dice7 = (int) (dice7 * 6);

            double dice8 = Math.random();
            dice8 = (int) (dice8 * 6);

            double dice9 = Math.random();
            dice9 = (int) (dice9 * 6);

            double dice10 = Math.random();
            dice10 = (int) (dice10 * 6);

            double total = dice1 + dice2 + dice3 + dice4 + dice5 +
                    dice6 + dice7 + dice8 + dice9 + dice10;

            if (total == 10) {
                results10.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 11) {
                results11.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 12) {
                results12.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 13) {
                results13.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 14) {
                results14.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 15) {
                results15.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 16) {
                results16.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 17) {
                results17.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 18) {
                results18.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 19) {
                results19.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 20) {
                results20.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 21) {
                results21.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 22) {
                results22.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 23) {
                results23.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 24) {
                results24.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 25) {
                results25.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 26) {
                results26.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 27) {
                results27.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 28) {
                results28.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 29) {
                results29.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 30) {
                results30.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 31) {
                results31.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 32) {
                results32.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 33) {
                results33.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 34) {
                results34.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 35) {
                results35.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 36) {
                results36.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 37) {
                results37.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 38) {
                results38.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 39) {
                results39.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 40) {
                results40.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 41) {
                results41.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 42) {
                results42.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 43) {
                results43.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 44) {
                results44.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 45) {
                results45.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 46) {
                results46.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 47) {
                results47.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 48) {
                results48.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 49) {
                results49.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 50) {
                results50.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 51) {
                results51.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 52) {
                results52.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 53) {
                results53.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 54) {
                results54.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 55) {
                results55.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 56) {
                results56.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 57) {
                results57.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 58) {
                results58.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 59) {
                results59.add("*");
            }
            if (total == 60) {
                results60.add("*");
            }


        }
        System.out.println("10: " + results10 + "\n" + "11: " + results11 + "\n" + "12: " + results12 + "\n" + "13: " + results13 + "\n" +
                "14: " + results14 + "\n" + "15: " + results15 + "\n" + "16: " + results16 + "\n" + "17: " + results17 + "\n" +
                "18: " + results18 + "\n" + "19: " + results19 + "\n" + "20: " + results20 + "\n" + "21: " + results21 + "\n" +
                "22: " + results22 + "\n" + "23: " + results23 + "\n" + "24: " + results24 + "\n" + "25: " + results25 + "\n" +
                "26: " + results26 + "\n" + "27: " + results27 + "\n" + "28: " + results28 + "\n" + "29: " + results29 + "\n" +
                "30: " + results30 + "\n" + "31: " + results31 + "\n" + "32: " + results32 + "\n" + "33: " + results33 + "\n" +
                "34: " + results34 + "\n" + "35: " + results35 + "\n" + "36: " + results36 + "\n" + "37: " + results37 + "\n" +
                "38: " + results38 + "\n" + "39: " + results39 + "\n" + "40: " + results40 + "\n" + "41: " + results41 + "\n" +
                "42: " + results42 + "\n" + "43: " + results43 + "\n" + "44: " + results44 + "\n" + "45: " + results45 + "\n" +
                "46: " + results46 + "\n" + "47: " + results47 + "\n" + "48: " + results48 + "\n" + "49: " + results49 + "\n" +
                "50: " + results50 + "\n" + "51: " + results51 + "\n" + "52: " + results52 + "\n" + "53: " + results53 + "\n" +
                "54: " + results54 + "\n" + "55: " + results55 + "\n" + "56: " + results56 + "\n" + "57: " + results57 + "\n" +
                "58: " + results58 + "\n" + "59: " + results59 + "\n" + "60: " + results60);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you start using variable names like `var1`,`var2`,`var3` to do the same thing, you should probably use an array or a `List` instead.

Comment: To add to what @RealSkeptic said, if you're using the copy+paste functionality more than once or twice - you're doing something wrong.

Comment: do this if they pay your by the number of lines of code:)

Comment: @RealSkeptic if I need to modify them after i make them (putting a "*" into the list every time the sum of the dice equals that number) how can i simplify my code?

Comment: @bayou.io I wish i was being paid for this at all haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use an nested arraylist for each trial?

```
public class TenDice {

    private static String strJoin(String[] lst, String delimeter) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s : lst) {
            if (s != null) {
                sb.append(s).append(delimeter);
            }
        }

        sb.setLength(sb.length() - delimeter.length());
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static class HistogramBar {
        private String[] data;
        private int top;
        private int size;

        public HistogramBar(int size) {
            data = new String[size];
        }

        public void add(String s) {
            data[top++] = s;
            size++;
        }

        public String[] getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public int getSize() {
            return size;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of trials: ");
        int trials = scan.nextInt();
        int numberDice = 10;
        int sidesPerDice = 6;

        HistogramBar[] results = getDiceTrialHistogram(numberDice, sidesPerDice, trials);
        System.out.println(results.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            int sum = i + 10;
            int length = results[i].getSize();
            System.out.printf("%d: %d\n", sum, length);
        }

        System.out.println("\nHistogram");

        for (HistogramBar histBar : results) {
            System.out.printf("|%s\n", strJoin(histBar.getData(), ""));
        }
    }

    private static HistogramBar[] getDiceTrialHistogram(int numberDice, int sidesPerDice, int trials) {
        int totalSum = numberDice * sidesPerDice;
        int size = totalSum - numberDice + 1;

        HistogramBar[] results = new HistogramBar[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            results[i] = new HistogramBar(trials);
        }

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++) {
            int total = 0;

            for (int rolls = 0; rolls < numberDice; rolls++) {
                total += r.nextInt(6) + 1;
            }

            HistogramBar totalList = results[total - numberDice + 1];
            totalList.add("*");
        }

        return results;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Enter number of trials: 
1000
10: 0
11: 0
12: 0
13: 0
14: 0
15: 0
16: 0
17: 0
18: 0
19: 0
20: 1
21: 1
22: 5
23: 7
24: 7
25: 20
26: 28
27: 24
28: 47
29: 40
30: 48
31: 43
32: 69
33: 58
34: 64
35: 77
36: 73
37: 62
38: 85
39: 33
40: 51
41: 36
42: 33
43: 19
44: 29
45: 10
46: 11
47: 7
48: 8
49: 4
50: 0
51: 0
52: 0
53: 0
54: 0
55: 0
56: 0
57: 0
58: 0
59: 0
1000
```

---

```
Histogram
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|*
|*
|***
|********
|************
|***********************
|*********************
|**************************
|**************************
|*********************************************
|***********************************************
|**********************************************************
|**********************************************************
|**************************************************************************
|*******************************************************************************************
|******************************************************************
|*******************************************************************
|*****************************************************
|********************************************************************
|**************************************************************
|**************************************
|********************************
|**************************************
|***************************
|******************
|***********
|******
|**********
|*****
|****
|*
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
```

Comment: My first solution was way off, sorry about that :)

Comment: this is great, how can i get the sums in the row next to the given histogram?

Comment: Update the printf statement to include `histBar.size()`

Comment: oh sorry, not the totals, the numbers like 10-60 that u have in the first part of the output i want in front of the histogram results

Comment: Then use the first loop, but change the length variable to be the `strJoin` of the list

Comment: `System.out.printf("%d: %s\n", sum, strJoin(results.get(i), ""));`

Comment: Do you know how I'd be able to do this with just arrays, instead of arrayLists?

Comment: Whoever is telling you to use only arrays should know that arraylist uses an array internally. Joking aside, you'd need to declare each array to be the maximum size of trials and you'd need to always know which index is the "top" of the histogram in order to add data there. You could make a wrapper object around a fixed size array to keep track of that, though. Basically, it's possible, but too much effort for any real use case

Comment: Sadly that's the way I'm being asked to do it :(

Comment: @MichaelG Okay, see edits for same answer using arrays

Comment: Welcome. I made one more edit because I messed up the math for the size of the array

Answer (score 1):

It's time to use the Stream API in Java 8.

To get the sum of 10 dice from 1 to 6 you can do

```
Random rnd = new Random();

long sum = IntStream.range(0, 10).map(i -> rand.nextInt(6) + 1).sum();
```

You can make many rolls and get the distribution of these.

```
Map<Long, Long> rollCount = 
       IntStream.range(0, roll)
                .map(r -> rnd.ints(10, 1, 7).sum())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
```

So this will roll 10 dice, `roll`s times and get a count of each of the results.

You can print the distribution with

```
rollCount.entrySet().stream()
         .sorted(e -> e.getKey())
         .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e + ": " + 
               IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(i -> "*").collect(Collectors.joining("")));
```

---

Lets say we can't use Java 8. We can use loops and a much simpler code.

```
 List<String> countList = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int i = 0; i <= 6 * 10; i++)
     countList.add(""); // start with nothing.
 Random rnd = new Random();
 for (int r = 0; r < roll; r++) {
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         sum += rnd.randInt(6) + 1;
     String stars = countList.get(sum);
     stars += "*";
     countList.set(sum, stars);
 }
```

Comment: I am in a Freshman-level Java course and as much as I'd like to use Stream API, my professor just wants us doing it his way for now, which only involves arrays and loops so far :/

Comment: @MichaelG -- even java is too "high level" as a teaching tool. they should really start from pointers...

Comment: @bayou.io I wish I had a say in that

Comment: @MichaelG You can use a couple of loops to do what you need. See my updated answer.

Comment: With the Stream API, `int sum = new Random().ints(10, 0, 7).sum();`

Comment: @AlexisC. I think the dice minimum is 1 not 0 esp as the sum of 10 dice is assumed to 10.

Comment: I think you really want `i < 6 * 10;` to go up to 60 -> `i <= 6 * 10;` Since the sum of 10 dice can be 60

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't pay attention `.ints(10, 1, 7)` ;)

Comment: @radoh a good point esp as this would be a bug which wouldn't show up easily in testing. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey the line of sum += rnd.randInt(6) + 1; gives me the error:
cannot resolves method randInt(int)

Comment: Well, you'd get IndexOutOfBounds once in a year or so ;), oh and `randInt` should be `nextInt`

Comment: understood, and @PeterLawrey how would I then print out in the form of a histogram the results of your loop? After all the point of the assignment is to create a histogram to show a bell curve

Comment: @MichaelG, that is really the easiest part, isn't it?

Comment: @radoh well when it's all printed out like in my original code, then yes, but using peter's new loop im not quite sure how to do it

Comment: @MichaelG you need to print out the `countList` using a loop.

Comment: with the numbers next to each star count?
like:
30: ***
31: *******
32: ***
etc?

Comment: @MichaelG yes, you want to a loop which counts from 10 to 60.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i get and know how to do that, but i dont get how to use countList to create a **vertical** histogram while using the loop from 10 to 60

Comment: @MichaelG you need to use `countList.get(i)` just like I did in my answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you used countLine.get(sum) ?

Comment: @MichaelG `sum` being the index I was looking up and the index is the sum you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8

```
int numberDice = 10;
int sidesPerDice = 6;
int roll = 1000;
Random random = new Random();

int[] freq = IntStream.range(0, roll)
    .map(r -> random.ints(numberDice, 1, sidesPerDice + 1).sum())
    .collect(() -> new int[numberDice * sidesPerDice + 1], (a, e) -> ++a[e],
        (a, b) -> { for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) a[i] += b[i];});

IntStream.range(numberDice, freq.length)
    .forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%4d:%4d:%s%n", i, freq[i],
        String.format("%" + (freq[i] + 1) + "s", "").substring(1).replaceAll(" ", "*")));
```

result

```
  10:   0:
  11:   0:
  12:   0:
  13:   0:
  14:   0:
  15:   0:
  16:   0:
  17:   0:
  18:   0:
  19:   0:
  20:   1:*
  21:   5:*****
  22:   6:******
  23:   5:*****
  24:  10:**********
  25:  18:******************
  26:  23:***********************
  27:  31:*******************************
  28:  40:****************************************
  29:  41:*****************************************
  30:  45:*********************************************
  31:  51:***************************************************
  32:  54:******************************************************
  33:  62:**************************************************************
  34:  72:************************************************************************
  35:  76:****************************************************************************
  36:  71:***********************************************************************
  37:  67:*******************************************************************
  38:  71:***********************************************************************
  39:  56:********************************************************
  40:  46:**********************************************
  41:  36:************************************
  42:  31:*******************************
  43:  24:************************
  44:  23:***********************
  45:  15:***************
  46:   5:*****
  47:   5:*****
  48:   5:*****
  49:   3:***
  50:   1:*
  51:   1:*
  52:   0:
  53:   0:
  54:   0:
  55:   0:
  56:   0:
  57:   0:
  58:   0:
  59:   0:
  60:   0:
```